# Hive treating the table's datatype as a different datatype than what is mentioned during table creation

Tags: hive

I am creating a table in Hive like below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS abc;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE abc (
  id string,
  name string,
  start_date timestamp,
  end_date timestamp
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = ",",
   "quoteChar"     = "\""
)  
LOCATION 's3://somes3/'
```

when i see the show create table

it shows every datatype as string but i had mentioned timestamp..

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `abc`(
  `id` string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
  `name` string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
  `start_date` string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
  `end_date` string COMMENT 'from deserializer')
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'quoteChar'='"',
  'separatorChar'=',')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://somes3/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1708002686')
```

This is voiding my date records and making queries fail.
Why is hive treating them as strings when i mentioned as timestamp. Please help me understand.